# Bug? In profile, my questions, badges, votes, etc. are all gone...

Tags: support, questions, reputation

At first I thought I wasn't logged in. But noticed my reputation shows up.

I get a big 0 for the rest of it:

[image]

Or did I just do something really, really bad and get it taken away? :\

Comment: As a result of this post, your profile (on meta) now shows one question and three tags, as it should :-).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize that that there was a difference between the two sites when it came to viewing questions/etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this on the Meta or the Main site?  They are separate in some portions.  Click on "meta" (top line on the StackExchange line) then on your name (same line that shows your name, total points badges, chat etc)...repeat when you click on "main" then your name.  This will show the questions that you have asked/answered/ etc for each site's subset

Comment: I didn't even realize they were separate. I'm not sure what I did, but after posting this question, I ended up finding my other questions and losing this one. (Obviously, I somehow toggled between the two again, but didn't know I was doing so). Thanks for your help.